# perl sort temporary directory

Tags: perl, unix, sorting

I ran into space issues on my machine and therefore the sort command in unix failed because of lack of space in /tmp. In order to circumvent this, I decided to run sort with the -T option allowing it to use some other directory for creating temporary files. here is the perl script I have

```
   my $TMPDIR              = "/home/xyz/workspace/";
    my $sortCommand         = "awk 'NR == 1; NR > 1 { print \$0 | \"sort -T \$TMPDIR -k1,1\" }' test > test.sort";
    system_call($sortCommand, "Sort");
    sub system_call {
      .......
}
```

this works perfectly on my desktop but when I run this in a different machine I get the error

"sort: cannot create temporary file: -k1,1/sortFoeXZx: No such file or directory"

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2):

You've got four levels of interpretation here (perl, shell, awk, shell). The sort shell command is

```
awk 'NR == 1; NR > 1 { print $0 | "sort -T $TMPDIR -k1,1" }' test > test.sort
```

so `$TMPDIR` is expanded by the inner shell. Apparently there is an environment variable of that name on your desktop machine but not in the other machine. The best fix is to make `TMPDIR` an environment variable and quote it properly (expanding it from Perl will cause trouble if its value contains characters that must be protected from awk or shell expansion).

```
$ENV{TMPDIR} = "/home/xyz/workspace/";
my $sortCommand = "awk 'NR == 1; NR > 1 { print \$0 | \"sort -T \\\"\$TMPDIR\\\" -k1,1\" }' test > test.sort";
```

It's strange to be relying so much on external tools from a Perl program. Ok, if `sort` overflows `/tmp`, then Perl's built-in `sort` is likely to run out of memory. So use [Sort::External](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Sort::External).

Answer (score 0):

You have escaped the `$` before the `TMPDIR` variable, which has resulted in `$TMPDIR` being passed through to the shell. As this is not defined in your environment, the command ends up as follows:

```
sort -T \ -k1,1
```

This has inadvertently escaped the following space character thus resulting in your error.

Comment: @ar: almost, but not quite: the shell doesn't see any \ there.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, you can some of your code by using [File::Tempdir](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::Tempdir), which will let you create a temporary directory or file with the appropriate user permissions, no matter your environment.

```
use File::Temp 'tempdir';
my $tempdir = tempdir(CLEANUP => 1);
my $sortCommand         = "awk 'NR == 1; NR > 1 { print \$0 | \"sort -T $tempdir -k1,1\" }' test > test.sort";
system_call($sortCommand, "Sort");
```